# Overlay with same functionality as close button.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a modal box that shows when a specific element in my app is clicked.

An overlay with .5 opacity and class "md-overlay" shows under modal box and in top of the rest of the content (I'm using z-index to layer them)

Inside the modal box, I have a close button with class "md-close" that when clicked by the user makes modal box and overlay stops from displaying in screen.

**What I'm trying to achieve:**

I want to add  the same feature of the button inside modal box to the overlay.

When the overlay with 100% width and height is clicked the modal box and overlay should not longer display.

**What I have tried:**

I tried adding the same class of the button to the overlay on html and I try adding the 
class of the overlay to the function on JS ('md-close, md-overlay').

**My current JS:**

```
    myModal.on('click', '.md-close', function (e) {
        var item = $(this),
            content = item.find('.md-video');

        item.removeClass('md-show');
        $videoDiv.appendTo('body');
        player.stopWaitForChanges();
        content.empty();
    });

    [].slice.call( document.querySelectorAll( '.md-trigger' ) ).forEach( function( el, i ) {

        var modal = document.querySelector( '#' + el.getAttribute( 'data-modal' ) ),
            close = modal.querySelector( '.md-close' ),
            video = $(modal).find('.md-video');

        function removeModal( hasPerspective ) {
            classie.remove( modal, 'md-show' );

            if( hasPerspective ) {
                classie.remove( document.documentElement, 'md-perspective' );
            }
        }
```

Should I must a have a new function just for the overlay since it isn't a button.

Comment: You could trigger the click on the close button, but that's a but nasty.

Comment: @stevemarvell How would you trigger it?

Comment: `$(selector).trigger("click")`